# Quantization of field with other complete orthogonal system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

I've learned the quantization of Klein-Gordon field using Fourier expansion. I understand that this process is kind of exchanging complex fourier coefficients to operator and makes it satisfying the canonical relation.

The result of usual process is given as
$$
\Phi(x) = \int (d^3k)a(k)e^{-ikx} + a(k)^\dagger e^{ikx}\bigr|_{k^0 = \omega_k}
$$

I wonder if I can do a quantization with other complete orthonormal systems, rather than $e^{ikx}$'s. (For example, radial fourier expansion or legendre polynomials)

If not, what makes it difficult? If we can, can you suggests the result with detail, the proper choice of commutation relation and Hamiltonian? Are they also determined by the quantization of classical Hamiltonian equation of motion as usual result be?

Comment: The exponentials are chosen as the complete orthogonal basis because they satisfy the classical equations of motion.

Comment: You also put $k^0=\omega_k$. That imples the definition of $\Phi$ is not a simple Fourier transform.

Comment: @SounakSinha I think that is not critical reason because that form is just a result of elliminating dirac delta function($\delta(k^2 - m^2)$) from original form.

Comment: @SounakSinha Do you mean that there is no other complete orthogonal basis which satisfies canonical quantization condition?

Comment: I see your point. Although I have not tried it, but if you write down the Klein-Gordan equation in radial coordinates, you won't get the standard dispersion relation ($|k^0|=\omega_k$). Then the basis functions won't be the standard exponentials, but most probably some sort of Bessel functions (with a new dispersion relation).

Comment: I don't think the canonical quantization condition has much to do with the mode expansion but rather imposes another equivalent commutation relation between the creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: I think any expansion should be equivalent to this one given the assumptions ($\mathcal{L}$ and the commutation relations). The logic goes: Starting with $\mathcal{L}$, get the KG equation. The general solution for the operator equation is the free expansion but with arbitrary operator coefficients $a(\vec{p})$. Then the commutation relations restrict these coefficients to be creation and annihilation operators, which can only be redefined up to a momentum-dependent phase. So this should be the general solution.. not sure how to argue how the phase must be chosen though.

Comment: You can find more information about this by searching for the keywords **Bogoliubov transformation**.